# Visual studio 2015 has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual studio 2015 (Enterprise Edition) previously it was working fine but after a month I started Visual Studio, I see errors:

> "Visual studio 2015 has stopped working"

When I start Visual Studio, I can't see the error code in the Windows crash reporter!

Edited: now it's showing this error

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of your plugins is corrupted. Specifically the "Experimentation Service Package". You can try launching Visual Studio in safe mode, which will launch without any plugins loaded. To do this:

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to launch the run dialog box
2. Enter `devenv.exe /SafeMode`
3. Press return

<sub>([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))</sub>

If Visual Studio launches you should be able to remove or repair the corrupt plugin from the package manager. If it doesn't work you should follow @ScottChamberlain's answer but with a few modifications:

> 1. Uninstall the current Visual Studio 2015
> 2. Reboot
> 3. Deleted everything inside `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\`
> 4. Install the latest version of Visual Studio 2015
> 5. Reboot

<sup>([source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/886cbbae-79ed-4f8a-b9e0-85db73329dd2/visual-studio-enterprise-update-2-installation-urgent-help-needed?forum=vssetup))</sup>

Answer (score -1):

I would uninstall and re-install visual studio. You still have the smiley face feedback icon in the top right corner, that was changed in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 to a person with a speech bubble.

[image]

I would just download the [Update 2 installer](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx) and just use that to do the reinstall.

Comment: But it's not opening when i click somewhere on visual studio it's stopped when click !

Comment: Uninstall visual studio, download vs2015.2.exe from the link I gave you and install that updated version and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: ok let me download it it's 5gb+ data :)